# Unable to use SetTabStops in a CListBoxCtontrol

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

I am unable to set tabstops in a ListBox control.
I have a dialog box with a ListBox control ,I am calling the SetTabStops function with 2 tabstops at position 5 and 10.

I am adding a string "testjob18\tAUTO" in the ListBoxControl .

But the output shows only testjob18 the AUTO doesn't get displayed.

I have set the property of the listbox control to UseTabstops is true.

the snippet of actual code inside the OnInitDialog of a property page is below

```
int positions[3] = { 5,10,15 };
m_BackupJobs.SetTabStops(2, positions);

for (it = jobsmap.begin(); it != jobsmap.end(); it++)
{
    CString tmp=it->first;

    if(jobbacktype[it->first]=="AUTO")
        m_BackupJobs.AddString(tmp+"\tAUTO");
    else
        m_BackupJobs.AddString(it->first);
}
```

Comment: Looks like "testjob18" has nine characters, so adding a tab after that will go beyond position 10. What happens if you set the second tab stop to (say) 12?

Comment: The positions are supposed to be in dialog units which I don't understand very clearly. positions are not the number of characters as I understand.

Comment: @HansPassant . I changed the tabs to 50,100,150 I also resized the list box but but AUTO is still not getting displayed.

Comment: tested with other values for e.g 100,150,200 but no success

Comment: Resolved. Thanks for your replies. I was painting the listbox twice. The second time removed my drawing of the first time. Sorry for inconvenience  caused.

Comment: Question is Answered by @HansPasssant